# _eventRepository подчёркнуто желтым цветом

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Ребят

_eventRepository подчёркнуто желтым цветом и пишет, что

Field 'HomeController._eventRepository' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

что делать можете подсказать?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly EventRepository _eventRepository;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var Getevent = _eventRepository.allEvent().OrderBy(n => n.Title);
        return View();
    }



public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
    {
        private readonly BookingDbContext ctx;

        public EventRepository(BookingDbContext ctx)
        {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Event> allEvent()
        {
            return ctx.Events;
        }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте перевести ошибку на русский, хотя бы Гугл транслейтом - в ней прямо сказано, что не так в коде.

Comment: В конструктор добавьте `_eventRepository = new EventRepository();`.

Comment: спасибо, все сработало